# Browserstack Connection Errors

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver-io, browserstack

I am using Browserstack and WebdriverIO for website automation. The website is behind a firewall and we're using browserstack.local, and we have been running into a few issues with the connection.

> Request failed with status 500 due to Error: unknown error:
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
>
> Request failed with status 500 due to Error: unknown error:
> net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
>
> Request failed with status 200 due to Error: [browserstack.local] is
> set to true but local testing through BrowserStack is not connected.

These issues are flaky, so we don't always see them. This is especially confusing for the last error, because browserstack.local is obviously set up if we can run tests most of the time.

On mobile devices we also see this error often.

> Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error: An unknown
> server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original
> error: chrome not reachable

Is this something we can fix, or is it a problem with Browserstack?

Answer (score 0):

I see the exception " [browserstack.local] is set to true but local testing through BrowserStack is not connected.". You can check why this occurs in the link:https://www.browserstack.com/question/779

Comment: Thank you. The problem is, if local testing was not set up in Browserstack (which it is), we would not be able to run the tests _at all_. But we can, it is only on some occasions that we get this error, so it seems Browserstack is being inconsistent.